# Parsing Two Arguments error: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying two pass two arguments from command line by using argument parser Library in python. 
One argument is the Input image that I am providing 
2nd argument is of the name in which my image gets saved.

Here is the Python Code :

```
import argparse
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-r", "--image", required = True, help = "Path to the image")
ap.add_argument("-l", "--location", required = True, help = "Filename")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
location = cv2.read(args["location"])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)             
im_thresh_gray = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, thresh)
mask3 = cv2.cvtColor(thresh, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
im_thresh_color = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask3)
cv2.imwrite(location, im_thresh_color)
print("[Info]:Processing Completed.")
```

The Command that I am providing is :

```
python image_thcolor.py --image image_test.jpg -l output.jpg
```

Here's the Error that I am getting :

> AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'read'

As I am new to python please tell me How can I parse two arguments.

Comment: is there any problem in this code also
```location = cv2.read(args["location"])```
@DeepSpace

Answer (score 0):

```
ap.add_argument("-l", "--location", required = True, help = "Filename")
```

means that the `--location` argument is required. That returns the error.

Comment: I want it to be required.  I think there's an error in this line 
```location = cv2.read(args["location"])```

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the location argument to be required:

```py
ap.add_argument("-l", "--location", required = True, help = "Filename")
```

You can either pass that argument to the script or use `required=False`

Comment: I think there's an error in this line
``` location = cv2.read(args["location"]) ```

Comment: This was not your initial question. If you want to ask another question, do so by opening a new question in SO